# Ktor Project application - Autoreload is disabled because the development mode is off

Tags: ktor, projekktor

Hi I dont finde Applocation.config in Ktor project and I get this error
INFO  ktor.application - Autoreload is disabled because the development mode is off.

how to solve this or do I need to add file Application.config manually

Comment: This is not an error but just a message about auto-reloading https://ktor.io/docs/auto-reload.html. Just ignore it if you don't care about auto-reloading.

Comment: but the server crush and couldn`t run

Comment: There is some other problem then. Could you please share the code for your server application?